# stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json returns 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, twitter, phirehose

I use Twitter streaming API (POST https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json) to monitor tweets. It worked up to 01/13/2014, and sinse that time it returns 403 error; from documentation I see that this error code means "The connecting account is not permitted to access this endpoint." I tried different applications and accounts, as well as 2 different servers (to make sure that it is not IP ban for any reason), but this error appears always. I know about API movement from HTTP to HTTPS, but it shouldn't be a problem, because I use HTTPS anyway.
Does anyone use filter.json successfully now and what may be a reason of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem, i use the 140dev streaming api PHP application.

I solved it by upgrading the Phirehose-library, according to this post:
http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-blog/upgrade-phirehose-now-for-continued-streaming-api-access/

BUT: I also needed to change the caps lock in OauthPhirehouse.php at the first line, from:

require_once('Phirehose.php');
to:
require_once('phirehose.php');

And i also had to change the name of Phirehose.php to phirehose.php (all small letters).

Comment: That is strange, as the filenames over on Github start with a capital letter: https://github.com/fennb/phirehose/tree/master/lib  If you have an upload or extract script that is lowercasing filenames, tell it to stop doing that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem which solved by http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-blog/upgrade-phirehose-now-for-continued-streaming-api-access/ and no need to do anything extra other than what mentioned on the link.